# Decryption with invalid key not always throws CryptographicException

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, aes, rijndaelmanaged

I'm using following settings for my crypto-service

```
        var cipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        cipher.KeySize = 256;
        cipher.BlockSize = 256;
        cipher.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126;
        cipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        cipher.Key = _key;
        return cipher;
```

For my service I wrote test which tries to decrypt encrypted data with invalid key.

```
    [Test]
    public void EncryptDecrypt_UsingInvalidKey_ShouldThrowCryptographicException()
    {
            var testInput = new TestInput();
            var encriptedData = _service.Encrypt(testInput.Input);
            var decrtryptServiceWithNewKey = GetService();

            Assert.Throws<CryptographicException>(() => decrtryptServiceWithNewKey.Decrypt(encriptedData));

    }
```

Th problem is that sometimes this test fails due to it doesn't throw CryptographicException(Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.) which I expected.

```
Initial Encryption Key :d/Ww5u5V/dV4FzYaFp8QEKeikFEFxaK9Z9ZBER1/y5A=

case 0) try decrypt with key :2pPmUsE4Erk+kUQPnmDCBzVlvvvePIjGJpi3cacJy1U=
                          iv :Hi4GbhuSKR5UUTyCgO+VNb/jQ+U1SfxXPPiAgiyCRhM=

  1)   key :40IeO1ZJF6miVFfmEaTkJDCus/EeiWBzzFqhvlxg/Js=
        iv :B535OzpMErNeSVeR98q5YEIikh0juk9YIsOBWop/N0I=
                                              Test pass

  2)   key :d1M0Mq4/5JIcp5oF8nvfj1e8hHv5uo0zSMf820ThnkM=
        iv :LAGLmg0LORGpHRWMKw3myPzuUjqlH4urn4+iMl248CE=
                                              Test pass

  3)   key :jDJdtNBUHe0CeNwf4VdyqpdMOAiDBFYZ0XJIXjw9BOw=
        iv :bCzj4E2jFkb3CRY5J6K1YjzsEBSn2ULjHNXtbZIbk2o=
                                              Test pass

  4)   key :zCbD4krNVS1wg8kjcW4+B7esMeJhCFK3PrlMrphpC0s=
        iv :rjLqP2L52KKu09tzJEuuIV9vRxpURI/Fz0R9vmOjsw8=

 Expected: <System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException>
 But was:  null
```

Could you please suggest why in some cases I can't get CryptographicException in my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the decrypted plaintext has the correct padding about once in eight times. This happens when the decrypted plaintext ends with `01` to `20`. The block size of 256 / 32 bytes makes for a valid padding for that particular range.

Padding should never be used to verify correctness of ciphertext/plaintext. It is even dangerous to do so as it may lead to padding oracle attacks. Instead you should use a (H)MAC over the ciphertext - adding an authentication tag to the ciphertext. A MAC should use a different key and should also include the IV. It is also possible to use a modern authenticated cipher such as GCM which allows using the same key - GCM/CCM/EAC etc already include the IV in the *authentication tag*.

CBC mode encryption *on it's own* can only be used for confidentiality, and that only when padding/plaintext oracle attacks are not applicable (i.e. it should never be used *as is* in a transport protocol). An authentication tag  is required to add integrity (what you are currently trying to test) and authenticity.

Note that [ISO10126](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1922/why-was-iso10126-padding-withdrawn) is obsolete and that Rijndael with a block size of 256 bits is not AES. So you are not using any standardized crypto at the moment.